# Extra new lines on base64 encode/decode in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64, decode, encode

I have written these utility functions:

```
import base64

def der2str(der):
    return bin2str( base64.encodebytes(der) )

def str2der(str_):
    return base64.b64decode( str2bin(str_) )

def bin2str(binary):
    return binary.decode('utf8')

def str2bin(str_):
    return str_.encode('utf8')
```

The I run:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = 'MIIEowIBAAKCAQEA6cVU+6GZyr1jaxvJcLEdRb9cicL/4Soe/HqN+gE/UdM5C71aG6HhNSplj1qi\nX8Abffen'
    print(test)
    print(der2str(str2der(test)))
```

but the output is:

```
MIIEowIBAAKCAQEA6cVU+6GZyr1jaxvJcLEdRb9cicL/4Soe/HqN+gE/UdM5C71aG6HhNSplj1qi
X8Abffen
MIIEowIBAAKCAQEA6cVU+6GZyr1jaxvJcLEdRb9cicL/4Soe/HqN+gE/UdM5C71aG6HhNSplj1qi
X8Abffen
```

Why am I getting these extra two new lines on the second print ?

**[EDIT]**
According to marked answer, using `return bin2str( base64.b64encode(der) )`, works fine as long as the input string `test` does not contain any `'\n'`.

If someone needs the newlines then the string must end on `'\n'` for the assertion `assert(test == der2str(str2der(test)))` to pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs for  [base64.encodebytes(s)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/base64.html#base64.encodebytes) state that it inserts newlines

> Encode the bytes-like object s, which can contain arbitrary binary data, and return bytes containing the base64-encoded data, with newlines (b'\n') inserted after every 76 bytes of output, and ensuring that there is a trailing newline, as per RFC 2045 (MIME).

You may want to use [base64.b64encode](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/base64.html#base64.b64encode) instead.

Comment: I tried it, but now the second output has not any new lines. But I want to get the same input, ```assert(test == der2str(str2der(test)))```

Comment: Given that `\n' isn't part of the base64 alphabet, I don't think that is possible - the decoder will assume embedded newlines are not part of the text to be decoded (I'm guessing).